# Не могу запустить второй python-файл через subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Мне нужно запустить **send_mess.py** из моего основного приложения **main.py**, чтобы два приложения работали параллельно друг другу.

```
def mailing_launch(self):
    global p
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'send_mess.py'])
    self.cancel_button.configure(state=customtkinter.NORMAL)
    self.start_button.configure(state=customtkinter.DISABLED)
```

Этот код работал нормально, но когда я перенес проект на другой компьютер, он отказывается запускаться:

***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'***

Если я использую

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['send_mess.py'])
```

то выдается ошибка:

***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'send_mess.py'***

Все файлы находятся в одной общей папке проекта.

[image: [enter image description here]()]